# Not getting content assistant/ intellisense in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, intellisense, content-assist

I having issue that content assistant / intellisense is working in methods such as onCreate but when I am calling it inside onClick method its not working.

I have attached screen shots of both scenarios.

[image: Working Content Assistant]

Above image show its working when I call it using ctrl + space in oncreate method

[image: Not Working Content Assistant]

Above image its not working

Also I am getting this error "The method onCreate(Bundle) of type ACTIVITY NAME must override or implement a supertype method"

shown in image

[image]

But activity is already overriding super method.

This is only happening in  this activity, other activities content assistant is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to Reset To Default Option in :

`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced`

In that "Api Proposal tools" is Main.

Then it will work, in that above window all options are for intellisense ( Ctrl + Space) only,  just have a look, if gets confusing then just set it to Default and ya that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

**Window -> preferences**

see the search box write here content assist

Copy and PASTE this string without Quote

"**.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789**"

in auto activation trigger as shows in figure below

[image]

Comment: did it , its not working, only in listview's onitemclicklistener of this activity its not working, rest whole project its working